# No logging from Hibernate-4.x on WildFly-8

Tags: java, hibernate, logging, log4j, wildfly

The question is for the webapp WAR with Spring+Hibernate deployed to WF8.
After webapp upgrade from Hibernate-3.x to 4.x the Hibernate logging stopped working.

The Hibernate-3.x was using **Slf4j**. The Hibernate Log4j logging was configured in the webapp with declaration in **jboss-deployment-structure.xml**:

```
<exclusions>
  <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
  <module name="org.slf4j"/>
  <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
</exclusions>
```

This declaration makes all logging classes to be loaded from WAR, not WF8.

The Hibernate-4.x is using **jboss-logging**. The additional exclusion

```
<exclusions>
    <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
    . . .
</exclusions>
```

initializes the webapp logger correctly but also breaks WF8 with Log4j error:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
```

Questions:
• How to enforce loading classes from **jboss-logging-3.x.Final.jar**
in the webapp and ignore classes loaded from this jar in WF8?

• How to initialize **jboss-logging** in the webapp and not to break
the WF8?

See also https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Excluding JPA does not help:

```
<exclude-subsystems>
  <subsystem name="jpa"/>
</exclude-subsystems>
```

Comment: Are you including Hibernate in your deployment or using Hibernate supplied by the container?

Comment: Hibernate+Spring+Logging are deployed in the WAR, not provided by container.

Comment: Are you excluding the `org.hibernate` module or probably better yet the `jpa` subsystem?

Comment: Excluding JPA does not help (updated the main question). I think, that the problem *not* with JPA or Hibernate on the server. These classes are loaded correctly from WAR. The server `jboss.logging` is reused by some other server systems and cannot be inited properly.

Comment: Okay, maybe I misunderstood then. Any server provided components will use the logging subsystem configuration. You can use your own configuration within your deployment, but only libraries within your deployment will use that configuration.

Comment: That is correct, I implemented *all* logging in the WAR. And it works. The question is why required `<module name="org.jboss.logging"/>` exclusion causes Log4j failed initialization error message on the server?

Comment: Possibly because Hibernate uses it and you include Hibernate. So Hibernate itself would log to the `org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager` because that is the provider used for the `org.jboss.logging` module.